# Coordinates for 'offset() or setOffset' in 'QGraphicsVideoItem' class

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsscene, qgraphicsitem

I am using Qt Creator 4.5.2 (Qt 5.9.5, GCC 7.3.0 64-bit) and running on Ubuntu 18.04
I am just trying to get live video stream from a IP camera or playback a pre-recorded video. I used 'QGraphicsView', 'QGraphicsScene' and 'QGraphicsVideoItem' method.

The coordinate of the top left cornet for 'view' is (300, 200) on the 'centralWidget'. The video did playback but its offset is off by (-300, -200). I had to use 'setOffset(300, 200)' method of 'QGraphicsVideoItem' to get the video at the correct position.

What coordinate is the 'offset' based on? I had expected it was based item's own coordinate. But, apparently, it is not. For my test, it is based on the coordinate of the 'centralwidget'. Do I get anything wrong?

Here is the document from QT for 'offset':
QGraphicsVideoItem will draw video using the offset for its top left corner.

Here is my code. I only copy & paste here the related part.

```
   mpView = ui->gvCam; // Top left corner offset is: (300, 200)
   mpScene = new QGraphicsScene;
//   mpScene = new QGraphicsScene(mpView);
   mpView->setScene(mpScene);
   mpScene->setSceneRect(mpView->x(), mpView->y(), mpView->width(), mpView->height());

   mpVideoItem = new QGraphicsVideoItem;
   mpPlayer = new QMediaPlayer(this, QMediaPlayer::StreamPlayback);

   mpPlayer->setMedia(QUrl::fromLocalFile("/home/test1/Videos/tmp1.avi"));
   mpPlayer->setVideoOutput(mpVideoItem);

   mpScene->addItem(mpVideoItem);
   QSizeF qsf1(mpView->width(), mpView->height());
   mpVideoItem->setSize(qsf1);
   mpVideoItem->setAspectRatioMode(Qt::IgnoreAspectRatio);

   // I have to set the following offset to get the video at the correct location. WHY?
   QPointF qpf1(mpView->x(), mpView->y());
   mpVideoItem->setOffset(qpf1);

   mpPlayer->play();
```

Thanks,

Steven

Comment: So, the code you have shown us is **not** your code that doesn't work, but rather sample code from somewhere else that **does** work?  Please provide a [MCVE] that demonstrates your problem, not sample code that works.

Comment: This is my code. It is part of a larger project. I only copy the related part.

Comment: Ok; then note you `setSceneRect` with an origin that happens to equal the offset you need later.  Try passing `0,0` at both `setSceneRect` and `setOffset`.

Comment: Thanks. Looks like it works. How do I mark this one as solved?

Comment: Feel free to self-answer below, then mark your self-answer as the solution.